# How to load a Statsmodels dataset in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I am trying to load a statsmodels dataset as I saw on a tutorial, but I keep getting an error.

```
import statsmodels as sm
import pandas as pd

data = sm.datasets.co2.load_pandas()
co2 = data.data

co2['ds'] = co2.index
co2.rename(columns={'co2': 'y'}, inplace=True)

co2.tail()
```

This is the error I am getting:

TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'

Comment: There is an open issue on github about this error. The workaround [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4775#issuecomment-476896523) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the problem is with original function "load_pandas", the "format" parameter no long exists in the new version of pd.DatetimeIndex, for details please refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html

```
  def load_pandas():
    data = load()
    # pandas <= 0.12.0 fails in the to_datetime regex on Python 3
    index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=data.data['date'][0].decode('utf-8'),
                             periods=len(data.data), format='%Y%m%d',
                             freq='W-SAT')
    dataset = pd.DataFrame(data.data['co2'], index=index, columns=['co2'])
    #NOTE: this is how I got the missing values in co2.csv
    #new_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='1958-3-29', end=index[-1],
    #                             freq='W-SAT')
    #data.data = dataset.reindex(new_index)
    data.data = dataset
    return data
```

so my solution of working around this is below:

1. load data into pandas DataFrame

   `co2 = pd.DataFrame(sm.datasets.co2.load().data)`
2. convert bytes into string and then datetime

   `co2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(co2.date.apply(lambda x: x.decode("utf-8")))`
3. set the date as index

   `co2.set_index('date',inplace=True)`

output:
[image]